# Liferay User Private Pages has no inheritance

Tags: templates, inheritance, liferay, private, propagation

within a project I encountered a problem with the Liferay inheritance/propagation. I added 3 pages to the "User private pages" Site template (as child pages of an already existing page, if that matters). I expected, that all users would have these pages available. But in fact, they have not. When opening one of the new pages, it says page not found. I can solve this by manually going to the private pages root page of that user, which seems to activate the propagation which leads to a generation of the new pages.

I wasn't able to find something related on the web. Is this a known bug? Am I just unable to find the correct settings?

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[LifeRay BugTracker, STATUS: Under Development, AGE: 11 weeks, 1 day](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-50964)

I recommend using the GIT to set LifeRay Portal to commit ID f5ce41ae4424e47230e7222294559f94656acd22.

This feature is reported to work under that commit ID. I am performing a GIT bisection to replicate this issue on my system, and attempt to fix it by applying the patch I will find at the commit ID captioned above.